# Why is my property injection attempt not injecting anything but undefined?

Tags: typescript, inversifyjs

I have an existing typescript project using inversify. I have defined a logger in my TYPES at `TYPES.ILoggger` and when I access the logger directly from my container it works:

```
import {ILogger} from "./interfaces/ILogger";
import {TYPES} from "./interfaces/TYPES";
import container from "./kernel/inversify.config";

const loggerFromTheContainer: ILogger = container.get<ILogger>(TYPES.ILogger);
loggerFromTheContainer.info("I WILL LOG"); // this works
```

So my setup should be fine.

I don't want to access the container directly but I want to use property injection. [InversifyJS' [README](https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS) provides an example:

> If you prefer it you can use property injection instead of constructor
>   injection so you don't have to declare the class constructor:
>
> ```
> @injectable()
> class Ninja implements Warrior {
>     @inject(TYPES.Weapon) private _katana: Weapon;
>     @inject(TYPES.ThrowableWeapon) private _shuriken: ThrowableWeapon;
>     public fight() { return this._katana.hit(); }
>     public sneak() { return this._shuriken.throw(); }
> }
> ```

and I try to follow that one.

Yet when I try to inject the logger through property injection, I suddenly get `undefined` as a logger and I don't know why:

```
@injectable()
class ShouldHaveLogger {
    @inject(TYPES.ILogger) private logger: ILogger;

    constructor() {
        this.logger.info("Hello World"); // this.logger will remain undefined
    }
}

new ShouldHaveLogger();
```

It will throw a generic

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'info' of undefined
```

as `this.logger` is not being injected. Yet why and how to fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The normal behavior of property injection is to let `inversify` create the instances for you. You are now describing a use-case, in which you create the instance of `ShouldHaveLogger` yourself (or another library is creating it for you).

This is also pointed out by the [docs](https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS/blob/master/wiki/property_injection.md#when-we-cannot-use-inversifyjs-to-create-an-instance-of-a-class)

In order to do that, you will need [inversify-inject-decorators](https://github.com/inversify/inversify-inject-decorators), as then you can inject the logger e.g. via `@lazyInject`.

You have to setup lazyInject using your container and your code should look like:

```
import {injectable} from "inversify";
import getDecorators from "inversify-inject-decorators";
import {ILogger} from "./interfaces/ILogger";
import {TYPES} from "./interfaces/TYPES";
import container from "./kernel/inversify.config";   

const {lazyInject} = getDecorators(container);

@injectable()
class ShouldHaveLogger {
    @lazyInject(TYPES.ILogger) private logger: ILogger;

    constructor() {
        this.logger.info("I am working now");
    }
}

new ShouldHaveLogger();
```

Will print depending on you logger implementation:

```
2019-01-30T09:47:54.890Z - info: "I am working now"
```